# Javascript - Is there any way to rename a file without updating referencing code?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where one independent module (not sure if that's the correct terminology. It's a set of scripts, data, and assets that work together) has art assets that are used by a completely different module. The second module is directly referencing files within the first module.

For various reasons, I would like to rename the files in the first module but doing so will break the second module. I do not have access to the second module to update it. Is there anything I can do in the first module (other than just duplicating the files) so that the second module will still work? This would need to work cross platform. Perhaps a symlink of some kind?

Comment: Referencing them how? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, they are SVG files and the other module displays them.

Comment: Displaying them how? Provide example code.

Comment: It's irrelevant. The point is that external code is directly accessing a file in my code that I want to move or rename. That could be an SVG that they are rendering in HTML, or a JSON file they're parsing, or a text file they're printing to the console. Regardless of the use case, they expect a file to be in a specific path and it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

you could you symlinks to create a "clone" of the file under a new filename and path, you may use a `"Hard" or "Soft"` symlink

> The difference between a hard-link and a symbolic-link (soft-link) A symbolic or soft link is an actual link to the original file, whereas a hard link is a mirror copy of the original file. If you delete the original file, the soft link has no value, because it points to a non-existent file

so if you have a file in, `/module2/assets/img.png` then you can use a sylink in the directory `module12/module2/assests/img.png` then you can use symlinks to point `module12/module2/assests/img.png -> /module2/assets/img.png`

Links:

- [SymLinks on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)
- [SymLinks on Links](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/symlink-tutorial-in-linux-how-to-create-and-remove-a-symbolic-link/)